# How can I dynamic hide swagger api?

Tags: annotations, swagger

I want hide swagger API in dependence of my deployment environment.
You can hide API by Annotation:

```
@Api(
        hidden = false)
public class MyRESTClass { ... }
```

It work fine, but is not dynamic. Is there another way to hide or not dynamic the swagger API?

see: [ApiMode Swagger](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.3.12/apidocs/index.html?com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModel.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a [spec-filter](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-core/src/main/java/io/swagger/core/filter/SwaggerSpecFilter.java) interface that you can implement for dynamic spec filtering.  You can extend [AbstractSpecFilter.java](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-core/src/main/java/io/swagger/core/filter/AbstractSpecFilter.java) and implement the methods that you want, which allows you to filter based on headers, parameters, etc.  It's very flexible.